# I2P-zero: run with predefined port

Tags: i2p, i2p-zero

How to choose a predefined port instead of letting I2P choose a random one?

For example, docker usage requires to know the port before running the router for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the ports in `~/.i2p-zero/config/router.config` before starting. There's plenty of example docker images available which do this, for example, in the main i2p distribution: [router.config](https://github.com/i2p/i2p.i2p/blob/master/docker/rootfs/i2p/router.config) & [Dockerfile](https://github.com/i2p/i2p.i2p/blob/master/Dockerfile).